# windows 2008 server R2 - remote desktop crashed after recent update

Tags: windows-server-2008, rpc, remote-desktop, rdp

I have updated the server recently (only those recommended security update from the windows server), after installation i had to restart the windows server, however after restarting the server, all the port are closed and I have no access with RDP (no access to sql server database, no access to tfs ...) .  currently i can access to the server only over the ssl and i have access only to the cmd consul on the server. can any body help?(the server is in the ISP and it is a dedicated server).

**Cause:**
installation first kb2667402 then the Sp 1 update

**effect:**

1. No RDP available
2. Windows blocks users right and give no right to start the services

***e.x*** 
The TFS Service uses TFSSERVICE USER, but win2008r2 block this user and say this user is not exist! 
what we have done:

1. uninstall the kb2667402

   after Uninstalling the kb2667402, i have exported the installed update and proved that the updated has been successfully removed.
2. delete and copy the old version of the rdpcorekmts.dll in system32
3. reconfiguration of the RDP and add a new port and rule for firewall
4. reset the firewall and add the new rule (we made a back up)
5. add the Teamviewer portable version with a fix password, but we cannot access to the TV, "Authentication rejected"
6. Installed RAdmin--> no access: the user name or password is wrong!
7. try to connect with Computer management from my pc to the server and get the error: RPC Sever is Unavailable
8. I have stop the firewall and had access from my pc  Event Viewer to remote server and could follow the errors on the server.

**Problem reported**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2667402

http://tmkilla.com/2012/04/windows-server-2008-r2-rdp-connection-error-sp1-kb2667402/

I have tried all the thing but didnt solve the problem. an idea how to solve the problem?